# magento: Status: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden when viewing HTTP Request and Response Header

Tags: magento

i used http://web-sniffer.net/ for testing my site, the result is below:

HTTP Request Header

```
Connect to ********** on port 80 ... ok

GET / HTTP/1.1[CRLF]
Host: **********[CRLF]
Connection: close[CRLF]
User-Agent: Web-sniffer/1.0.44 (+http://web-sniffer.net/)[CRLF]
Accept-Encoding: gzip[CRLF]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8[CRLF]
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5[CRLF]
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,UTF-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7[CRLF]
Cache-Control: no-cache[CRLF]
Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/[CRLF]
```

HTTP Response Header

```
Name    Value   Delim
Status: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date:   Tue, 09 Apr 2013 04:58:52 GMT   
Server: Apache  
Expires:    Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT   
Cache-Control:  no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0  
Pragma: no-cache    
Set-Cookie: frontend=d661c78db51b210814a8196466c81849; expires=Tue, 09-Apr-2013 05:58:52 GMT; path=/; domain=www.lebunnybleu.com; HttpOnly  
Connection: close   
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked 
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

so how to fix "Status: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP error 403 – Forbidden means that access to the file/folder you are trying to open has been denied, either on purpose or due to a misconfiguration.
The two most common causes of a "403 Forbidden" error are:
1. Incorrect File Permissions
2. "No Index" in .htaccess file is improperly used

Correcting a 403 Forbidden Error:-

> 1. First, you will want to check the file permissions that each of your files has set. If a file or folder is set to "777" which is
>      "world" writable for security reasons the 403 error will be displayed
>      to protect your website from hacks. Folders should have the
>      permissions set to "750" or "755" and files should be set to "644"
> 2. Once you have verified all the permissions are correct and the issue still persists, you will need to check your .htaccess file.
>      Please keep in mind that you can have multiple .htaccess files in your
>      account, so you may need to search / modify .htaccess files other than
>      public_html/.htaccess. For example, if you have an addon domain
>      located at public_html/addon_domain, you'll need to check any
>      .htaccess files within that folder as well. If one of the lines in the
>      actual file says "Options All -Indexes" then simply remove "-Indexes"
>      and save the file.

Comment: Kya baat hai Rosan ji :)